# How to present ViewController programatically from Swift to Obj C within data passing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have 2 View Controllers. When pressing a button on the first VC, it will navigate to the second one. The second one is a table view to show bluetooth peripheral devices. If I create a triggered segue on Main.storyboard by holding control button + drag my mouse...everything will run well, bluetooth devices will appear in the table view. However, I wanna pass a string to the second VC, so I used the code below to present the second VC within the string...

```
let 2VC = SecondViewController()
    2VC.stringData = "test"
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(2VC, animated: true)
```

...and then I received that string on the secondVC but the table view show nothing. To make it clearer, those table view cells show empty, although The Console Output shows the code still work well. I do not know what the point is?

p/s: the first VC (swift code)
the second VC (obj-c code)

[image]

Comment: Where did you assign the tableView datasource? From your storyboard?

Comment: share some more info like tableview delegate & data source methods.

Comment: You must initialize SecondViewController with xib file or storyboard

Answer (score -1):

I have change my above code to:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let 2VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
2VC.stringData = "test"
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(2VC, animated: true)
```

then everything work well.